# Relay mail from an application server to a relayhost

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I've a server which serves as the central mail server, which relays mail to SES. The main.cf looks like this:

```
relayhost = email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
```

I have several application servers, which all need to potentially send email. So I'd want to be able to send the mail via the central mail server. While I can think of a Message Queue solution to achieve this, where in each application server puts the mail job into the MQ, and then mail server can simply consume those jobs, process it and send actual email. However, that just seems too much of handling for something that should be available out of the box.

I think there should be some postfix solution available to achieve this. Is there any way postfix on an Application server can "relay" the mail to the "central mail server" which then can actually relay it via the relayhost (SES)?

Comment: Just specify your central mail server as the `relayhost`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: No I've not tried that yet. What would be the sasl_passwd (username/password) to be used in that case?

Comment: You'd  create your own username/password pair(s).  The application server uses similar relay setup to what you reproduce in the question; the central mail server should accept incoming mail on (e.g.) port 587 requiring encryption - specify in the `smtpd_` parameters.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, and I'm constantly getting this in maillog when I try to send email from application server:

D6E73140837: to=<XXX@YYY.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to XXXXXX:587: Connection refused)

I've enabled 587 port as incoming on the central email server, and also enabled connections from outside by doing this in main.cnf:

inet_interfaces = all